# Bypassing company single-sign-on using requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url_0 = "https://xyz.ecorp.abc.com/"

r = requests.get(url_0, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('username', 'password'))
r.text
```

I am trying to get data from this site but when I log in using `requests` library then my company has additional layer of security tied to it which directs me to Single sign on page. Is there a way to bypass that and go to the above URL?

Below is the response from server:

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
     <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
         function redirect({
             window.location.replace("https://abc.xyz.com/CwsLogin/cws/sso.htm");
         } 
     </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY onload="redirect()"></BODY>
</HTML>
```